# JavaScript: Return property values only

Tags: javascript

I want to implement a function that returns an array of property values if the value is primitive (non-object or array) and property name starts with prefix.

For example

```
var values = function (obj, prefix) { ... }

var testObj = {
    'a': 1, 
    'ab': [
        {
            'c': 2, 
            'ac': true
        }
    ]
};
```

As a result of `values(testObj, 'a')` function invocation I expect to get such  array of primitives: `[1, true]`.

Here is my try:

```
var values = function (obj, prefix) {
    var res = [];

    for (var i in obj) {
        if (i.startsWith(prefix)) {
            var v = obj[i];

            if (typeof v === 'object') {
                var r0 = arguments.callee(v, prefix);
                res.push(r0);
            } else {
                res.push(v);
            }
        }
    }

    return res;
};
```

But it returns a wrong result: `[1, []]`. How can I fix it?

Comment: please add the wanted result, too.

Comment: @NinaScholz `[1, true]`

Comment: why do you want redundant information once you are returned with 1 what is the point of having `true`

Comment: And shouldn't the expected result be `[1, [[true]]]`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a recursive approach for the values, you need.

```js
function values(obj, prefix) {
    var result = [];
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (k) {
        if (obj[k] !== null && typeof obj[k] === 'object') {
            result = result.concat(values(obj[k], prefix));
        } else if (k.startsWith(prefix)) {
            result.push(obj[k]);
        }
    });
    return result;
}

var testObj = { 'a': 1, 'ab': [{ 'c': 2, 'ac': true }] },
    result = values(testObj, 'a');
 
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

<sup>(My city energy is weak.)</sup>

Where the main problem is in the `i.startsWith(prefix)` condition. It avoids you to enter a object without property name including @prefix inside a array. For example:

```
{ a: 1, ab: [ /* 0: { 'c': 2, 'ac': true } */ ] }
```

As you see, the object in the array is ignored since its property name is `0`, that's its index.

If you really want to get this result: `[1, true]` you'll have to skip the array and return the first item to `res.push`.

```
var values = function (obj, prefix) {
    var res = [];

    for (var i in obj) {
        if (i.startsWith(prefix)) {
            var v = obj[i];

            if (typeof v === 'object') {
                var isArray = v instanceof Array;
                var r0 = arguments.callee(isArray ? v[0] : v, prefix);
                res.push(isArray && r0.length === 1 ? r0[0] : r);

            } else {
                res.push(v);
            }
        }
    }

    return res;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code works.

```
var testObj = {
  'a': 1, 
  'ab': [
    {
      'c': 2, 
      'ac': true
    }
  ]
};

var values = function (obj, prefix) {
    var res = [];

    if(Array.isArray(obj)){
      for(var j in obj){
        res = res.concat(arguments.callee(obj[j], prefix));
      }
    }
    else if(typeof obj == "object") {
      for (var i in obj) {
        if (i.startsWith(prefix)) {
          var v = obj[i];

          if (typeof v === 'object') {
            res = res.concat(arguments.callee(v, prefix));
          } else {
            res.push(v);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return res;
};

console.log(values(testObj, 'a'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for;

```js
var testObj = {
                'a': 1, 
               'ab': [
                      {
                        'c': 2, 
                       'ac': true
                      }
                     ]
              };
  getValues = (o,x) => Object.keys(o)
                             .reduce((p,k) => p.concat(typeof o[k] === "object" ? getValues(o[k],x)
                                                                                : k.indexOf(x) >= 0 ? o[k]
                                                                                                    : [])
                                     ,[]);
console.log(getValues(testObj,"a"));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var testObj = {
  'a': 1, 
  'ab': [
     {
        'c': 2, 
        'ac': true
     }
   ]
};
var res = [];
var values = function (obj, prefix) {
  for (var i in obj) {
     var v = obj[i];
     //Prefix check line can be moved here if you want to check the prefix for object
     if (typeof v === 'object') {
        arguments.callee(v, prefix);
     } else {
        if (i.startsWith(prefix)) { //Prefix Check
           res.push(v);
        }
     }
  }
  return res;
};
console.log(values(testObj,'a'));
```

Please check this, this gives the output that you wanted.